# Node: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am generating a big object and attempting to safe these into a `.json` file. However, even using streaming, it appears that the object is caching up the heap and never being released.

This is the function which I call:

```
saveObjectAsJSON (o: any, filename: string) {
    const content = JSON.stringify(o);
    const wstream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    wstream.write(content);
    wstream.end();
}
```

It works for smaller objects, but I am generating quite a big one now(about 1 million objects at the outer level). Does this reach the capacity and capabilities of Node? Should I use Mongo or something to store/retrieve them in?

Error trace:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6583:0x102801e00]   474566 ms: Mark-sweep 2948.9 (4039.7) -> 2948.8 (4024.7) MB, 6035.6 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[6583:0x102801e00]   480764 ms: Mark-sweep 2948.8 (4024.7) -> 2948.8 (3993.7) MB, 6198.0 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[6583:0x102801e00]   487025 ms: Mark-sweep 2948.8 (3993.7) -> 2948.8 (3963.7) MB, 6260.8 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x934a4ba5529 <JSObject>
    1: fromString(aka fromString) [buffer.js:336] [bytecode=0x9340cbd6b51 offset=161](this=0x934c6e822d1 <undefined>,string=0x9350da7d189 <Very long string[936824012]>,encoding=0x934a4bb6419 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: from [buffer.js:189] [bytecode=0x9340cbd6611 offset=14](this=0x934616bd3b1 <JSFunction Buffer (sfi = 0x934e8b83821)>,value=0x9350da7d189 <Very long string[936824012]>,encodingOrOffse...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalTryCatch::~FatalTryCatch() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*, int, int*, int) const [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: node::StringBytes::Write(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long, v8::Local<v8::Value>, node::encoding, int*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: node::Buffer::(anonymous namespace)::CreateFromString(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x39ffa47042fd
14: 0x39ffa47bd196
```

Comment: `about 1 million objects at the outer level` that screams for a database or a key value store

Comment: @JonasW. this is just to produce some test data for another part of the system; It just needs to run once, and that's it. It is fine if it can be optimized to complete, but run for a long time(hours, even). But perhaps Node as a language comes short in this regard?

Comment: maybe you should use a json serializer that outputs a stream? http://oboejs.com sounds good

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks.